# Angular "Unknown provider" error when using $filter in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got a directive that needs to use angular's $filter in the code. However, when trying to use it, I'm getting an error:

`[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: FilterProvider <- Filter`

Here's a minimal example of what's causing the error: http://jsfiddle.net/5tLtj3nh/

I'm stumped trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Do you want to filter array by `query` string? If so, you should use `$filter('filter')([], 'query');` BTW, better to post code here

Comment: can you please add your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the `$filter` service incorrectly.

You have to get a filter from `$filter` service first like this:

```
var filterFilter = $filter('filter');
filterFilter([], 'query');
```

or a one liner:

```
$filter('filter')([], 'query');
```

In case you are confused, the `'filter'` filter is one of the build-in filters of angularjs.

There are many more, see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter

- currency
- date
- filter
- json
- limitTo
- lowercase
- number
- orderBy
- uppercase

**Tip:** You could also inject an individual filter to use like this:

```
app.directive('testDirective', ['filterFilter', function(filterFilter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>testDirective</div>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            filterFilter([], 'query');
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Looks like I completely missed that in the docs. Thanks for clarifying that for me.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, your syntax is wrong. To use the `filter` `$filter` the syntax as per the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) is:

```
$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)
```

Assuming you want to filter based on the `query` string you'll need:

```
$filter('filter')([], 'query')
```

Comment: Accepted runTarm's answer since I can only accept one, but this also solved my issue, so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

for working plnkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/US6xE4h0gD5CEYV0aMDf?p=preview

check how your angular environment is setup.
Follow Steps:

check if your Index.html has loaded script.

```
<script src="scripts/angular-filter.js"></script>
```

check if $filter is used in your controller

```
    (function () {
    'use strict';
    var controllerId = 'controllerName';
    angular.module('myApp')
    .controller(controllerId, ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$timeout', 'security', '$filter', functionName]);
    function functionName($rootScope, $scope, $timeout, security, $filter) {
        // your controller code.
    }})();
```

You html page is using FilterBy

```
    <tr ng-repeat="row in tableList | filterBy: ['col1','col2','col3'] : vm.listFilter">
        <td class="text-left">{{row.col1}}</td>
        <td class="text-left">{{row.col2}}</td>
        <td class="text-left">{{row.col3}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Don't forget to include dependency while loading angular

```
    var app = angular.module('app', [
    'common',           // These are just example, can be anything
    'common.bootstrap', 
    'security',         
    'nsPopover', 'angular.filter'
    ]);
```